# How to Fix 'openai.Completion not supported' Error in Google Cloud Function Using OpenAI SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, openai-api

I'm working on a Google Cloud Function that is triggered by a Make.com automation. The function's purpose is to generate text using the OpenAI API, and then place this text in an Airtable record. This same function was previously working fine in a Google Colab environment just two weeks ago.

However, I'm now facing an issue when deploying it as a Google Cloud Function. I receive the following error message:
`You tried to access openai.Completion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.`

Do anyone know how to solve it ?

My code:

```
import os
import openai
import requests

# Set your OpenAI API key from environment variables

openai.api_key = os.environ.get('OPENAI_API_KEY')

def generate_email_content_with_browser(website_url):
try:
prompt = (
# Add the prompt here
)

        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-4",
            messages=[
                {"role": "system", "content": prompt},
                {"role": "user", "content": f"Visit the website at {website_url}."}
            ],
            temperature=0.7  
        )
        email_content = response.choices[0].message.content
        print(f"Generated email content for {website_url}: {email_content}")  # Debug print
        return email_content
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating email from {website_url}: {e}")
        return ""
```

I'm expecting the openAI function to work, and generate the email.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the new form of the client call:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-4",
    messages=[
             {"role": "system", "content": prompt},
             {"role": "user", "content": f"Visit the website at {website_url}."}
    ],
    temperature=0.7
)
```

Note that the client automatically recognizes that environment variable with the API key, you don't need to include it.

For more details, check out the docs:
https://platform.openai.com/docs/libraries